# Проблема с ресайзом нескольких фото в Firefox

Tags: javascript

Добрый день! Помогите решить проблему. Есть скрипт, который должен принимать несколько фото, уменьшать до нужного размера и передавать на сервер. В хроме скрипт работает как положено, а в лисе нестабильно, то есть могут пройти обработку все фото , но чаще в data прилетает значение "data:,". При этом, обычно, последнее фото обрабатывается нормально. В чем может быть причина? Подозреваю, что лис просто обрывает работу drawImage несмотря на onload.

```js
var max_height = 1000,
  max_width = 1000;
var data, i = 0;
var read = function() {
  readFile = function() {
    var file = files[i];
    if (file) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
      reader.onload = function() {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = reader.result;
        draw = function() {
          var width = img.width,
            height = img.height;
          if (width > height) {
            if (width > max_width) {
              height *= max_width / width;
              width = max_width;
            }
          } else {
            if (height > max_height) {
              width *= max_height / height;
              height = max_height;
            }
          }
          var dimage = new Image();
          dimage.src = img.src;
          dimage.onload = function() {
            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            ctx.drawImage(dimage, 0, 0, width, height);
            data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
            i++;
            read();
            console.log(data);
            //ajaxUpload(data);
          }
        }
        draw();
      }
    }
  }
  readFile();
}
read();
```

Comment: А ошибки в консоли Firefox появляются?

Comment: никаких ошибок, кстати часто не обрабатывается единичное фото, при загрузке нескольких хоть 1-2 обрабатываются почти всегда